# How to find the principal argument of $z^4$, given $z$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having trouble with a homework question.

Let $ z= \cos\left(\frac{3}{4}\pi\right)+i \sin\left(\frac{3}{4}\pi\right)$.

What is the principal argument of $z^4$ in radians?

Is it undefined? If not then I am lost...

Comment: By “z4” do you mean $z^4$?  [Here's how to format mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I edited your post assuming that "z4" is $z^4$. Make sure it's what you meant.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: hint: use polar notation, $z^4=e^{i\frac{3}{4}\pi}$

Comment: @cjferes: I would say that you thought $z^4=\left(e^{i\frac{3}{4}\pi}\right)^4$

Comment: yeah, that's what i meant.

Comment: The answer was 0

Answer (score 1):

Use de Moivre's formula, with

$$\cos\frac34\pi+i\sin\frac34\pi=:\text{cis}\frac34\pi=:e^{\frac34\pi i}\;\;:$$

$$z^4=\left(\text{cis}\frac34\pi\right)^4=\text{cis} \,3\pi$$